# How to check a Number in mxml?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

I'm trying to check if `Number` is defined in flex `mxml`. Both of the following does not work:

```
<Checkbox visible="{isNan(obj.number)}"/>
<Checkbox visible="{obj.number == null}"/>
```

How is this done correctly?

Comment: define a getter function like in AS3, make it bindable, use this getter. Alternatively, try putting the condition in conditional braces like so `isVisible={(obj.number == null)}`.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the function name is case sensitive: `isNaN()`!

Comment: Just for reference, all of AS3 is case sensitive. So make sure it always matches. Additionally, I don't believe what you are trying to do is bindable. It will work on object instantiation but it won't change later on when `obj.number` changes.